# Display date to view with a M-D-Year

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel, with regards to displaying the date to the view with the MM-DD-YYYY format

```
@extends('layouts.common')
@section('title' ,'Administrator | Category')
@section('contents')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">All Categories</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Category Name</th>
                            <th>Published At</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="{{ url('/category', $category->id) }}"> {{
                                    $category->name }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{$category->published_at }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{ route('category.edit',$category->id) }}"><i
                                    class="icon fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a><i
                                class="icon fa fa-times"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection @section('js') {!!Html::script('assets/js/jquery.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!} @endsection
```

With regards to that i would like to display to the view the {{$category->published_at }} data into that format. Please help thanks

Comment: The third option is `{{date('m-d-Y',strtotime($category->published_at))}}`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow way below

```
{!! date('d-m-Y', strtotime($model->start_date)) !!}
or
{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($model->start_date)) }}
```

**I Hope Help You!**

Answer (score 0):

In your `Category` model

```
public $dates = ['published_at'];
```

Then in view you can use

```
$category->published_at->format('m-d-Y')
```

Further reading: [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Extends **Skysplit** answer 
**In Category Model**

```
public function getPublishedAtAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['published_at']->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

And never worry about published_at again. **Just**

```
$category->published_at
```